# Does permuting the columns of a matrix affect its range?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Intuitively it feels that permuting the order of the columns of some matrix $A$ would not affect the range in any way, but I have neither managed to found a proof or proof the statement myself. Specifically, let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ so that the $i$th column vector of $B$ is the $\sigma(i)$th column vector of $A$. Is $\mathrm{Range}(A) = \mathrm{Range}(B)$? It feels so obvious that I can only wave my hands and claim that for $v \in \mathrm{Range}(A) \Longleftrightarrow v = Ax, x \in \mathrm{C}^{m} \Longleftrightarrow v = x_1A_1 + x_2A_2 + \dots + x_cA_c$ we can i.) reorder the sum so that the order of the summand columns of $A$ match columns of $B$, ii.) find appropriate new scalars, so that $v = y_1A_{\sigma(1)} + \dots y_cA_{\sigma(c)}$ for some $y \in \mathbb{C}^{m}$.

Edit: Am I making this too hard for myself as the range of matrix $A$ is the span of its column vectors?

Comment: Your first intuition is right, if you have $v\in Range(A)$, $v=x_1 A_1+\cdots + x_c A_c$, you can just apply $\sigma$ to the coefficients of the vector $x$. Hence $v=x_{\sigma(1)} A_{\sigma(1)}+\cdots+x_{\sigma(c)} A_{\sigma(c)}$ and so $v\in Range(B)$

Comment: The span of a $\text{set}$ of vectors clearly doesn't depend upon the order of vectors, otherwise the definition of span itself would not be well posed(because a $\text{set}$ is an unordered collection). Precisely the definition is well posed because vector sum is commutative, and this allows to reorder the summands as tou did. And clearly in your case a possible choice is $y_i=x_{\sigma (i)}$

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández This might be borderline pedantic, but given the permutation $\sigma$, how would you apply it algebraically in the equation $v = Ax$?

Comment: @Qwaster If you want to be extremely rigourous ,in any algebra book you'll find a theorem of generalised commutative property. In a commutative structure(i.e. $x+y=y+x$): $x_1+...+x_n=x_{\sigma (1)}+...+ x_{\sigma (n)}$. You can prove this by induction on $n$

Comment: The structure clearly needs also to be associative other wise the expression:$x_1+...+x_n$ is meaningless.

Comment: @Qwaster Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough when writing the comment. I don't know if there exist a formal way to apply $\sigma$ to that kind of equation because we would have to define the meaning of $\sigma(v)$ in a non-problematic way. I used $\sigma$ in a less formal way to give the same idea as the other comment to choose the new vector (y_1,\dots,y_c)..